# Making flex.exe on windows

Tags: c++, c, flex-lexer

I have downloaded the source code for flex from [the Flex repository](https://github.com/westes/flex/releases). The file is flex version 2.5.35 in tar.gz. Now how can I make flex.exe from this source code?

Answer (score 2):

Just download the binary packages instead, they are available here: http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/flex.htm alternatively you need to use the makefile the source comes with to compile it (by passing as a parameter to gcc's `make.exe`).

Answer (score 0):

You have two options:

1. Download [this](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/flex.htm) instead and follow the directions in the link to download the installer and dependencies.
2. Use something like [7-Zip](http://www.7-zip.org/) to extract the files and follow the included instructions for compilation (much more difficult).

The former sounds like the right answer for you unless you need a feature of the latest version and have the GNU toolchain available on your platform.  I don't know if `flex` will compile with the MS compiler without lots of pain.

Comment: Actually I am looking for the latest version.

Comment: What toolchain do you want to use for the build?

Comment: I can use any toolchain that will provide me flex.exe that I can use on windows platform.

Comment: It's potentially more complicated than that....if you need to link to libflex, you either can go full Cygwin or use MinGW to make libs that will link with the MS toolchain.

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to build it from source by yourself on a Windows machine (which may or may not work), you will want to install [Cygwin](http://www.cygwin.com/install.html) first.

Comment: Could you let me know what to do next?

Comment: Cygwin is not my preference...I would go for [MinGW](http://www.mingw.org/) for the build environment, as it creates native Windows executables and requires less download mess.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this: http://sourceforge.net/projects/winflexbison/
This is latest flex-bison tools ported to windows without extra dependencies (like m4.exe or Cygwin dlls)